# Catch block coverage with no dml/query in try block

Tags: code-coverage, try-catch

Is there a way to cover the following catch block without of course doing test.isRunning.

```
Try{
     Id bId = Func1();
     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result = Obj1.SObjectType.getDescribe(); 
     pageRef = new PageReference('/' + result.getKeyPrefix()); 
     pageRef.setRedirect(true); 
}
catch{
    // blah blah blah
}
```

Func1:

```
public id Func1(){
    Id batchProcessId; 
    ClassA BatchX = new ClassA(); 
    batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(BatchX); 
    return batchProcessId;
}
```

Comment: what is Func1? Can we simulate exception inside of Func1 ?

Comment: Func1:  public id Func1() {                          
         Id batchProcessId; 
              ClassA BatchX = new ClassA();       
              batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(BatchX); 
              return batchProcessId;   
     }

Comment: Do you have any code inside ClassA constructor to simulate exception inside of new ClassA() ?

Comment: I don't know how can that be done when we are not passing any parameter in the constructor. ---------ClassA BatchX = new ClassA();--------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try some approach like this

```
public class ClassA{
@testVisible static Boolean raiseException{ get{ if ( raiseException == null ) raiseException = false; return raiseException; } set; }

public ClassA(
    if (raiseException)  throw SomeFakeException();
)

}
```

Then in test

```
testMethod static void coverCatchBlock() {
   ClassA.raiseException = true;

   // perform test
}
```